# Python and Python 3 are different?

Tags: command-line, python

I went to run script that need python installed
I got error

```
./run.sh: line 825: python: command not found
```

I install python 3.8 using this guide
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu
But I still got same error

1. Python and Python3 are different?
2. How to solve this error?

Comment: Please provide your OS & release; as default versions of python(3) differ based on release.  Python 2 is EOL & thus isn't supported by any OS; though can be installed for *legacy* apps that haven't been ported to a *supported* system. You can have `python` execute `python3` easily but this may or may not be what you want; as the effects may vary on your release & what application you want it for (*ie. how old or unsupported is the python app you want to use?*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are different. All recent Ubuntu installations use `python3` only (and you don't need to install Python 3, as it's already on your system).

To run programs that point to `python`, install the package `python-is-python3`:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Or manually create a symlink to `python3` (which basically is what the above package does):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

If the application you run require an earlier version of Python, you can instead install Python 2 from the `universe` repository:

```
sudo apt install python2
```

Only do this if you really need it, since Python 2 is no longer supported.